# Where is appropriate location to make Http requests inside a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I currently make http requests inside the browserAction popup set via `default_popup` in manifest.json.

I was able to make it work, the problem is if i close the popup before the http request finishes then it gets cancelled, as in there's no network requests even logged inside networks in devtools.

I know i can only make http requests in extension scripts like **background scripts** and **browserAction** popup.

Is there any rule of thumb on where to do http requests?

I assume it's on **background scripts** since they just lurk there inside the browser.

Comment: The only rule is the one you already discovered so yes you need a background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm, yup. Was able to fix my issues by deferring the logic to the background script by using message passing between popup and background script